# Java Multiple Maps Check if Contains

Tags: java

I have around 30 HashMaps of data and i have run into a situation where i need to check if a certain value exists inside any of the hashmaps.

For example

```
if (map1.contains(value)){ //remove the value with map1.remove() }
if (map2.contains(value)){ //remove the value with map2.remove() }
if (map3.contains(value)){ //remove the value with map3.remove() }
//and so on
```

I could just do that 30 times but im not sure how efficient that would be, is there a much cleaner way to do this? any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Why would you have 30 maps in the first place? That certainly is a code smell. Improve the design.

Comment: Are you really wanting to check the values or the keys? If it is the values (which is what you appear to be showing), are the values guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yes, i have thought of a different way to do it which would be more effiecent and not having to check each map, what i need to do though is somehow turn a string value "String s = "someHashMapName"; and be able to reference a Map with the same name as that string, not sure how i can convert the string though,

Answer (score 2):

30 Maps are hard and i dont know about your use case.

You can hold it in a list and iterate over it but you should refactor the class.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> testList = new ArrayList<>();
...//add maps

    for(Map<String, Object> map : testList){
        map.containsKey(...)
    }
```

Comment: I want to store player wins/loses of each of the gametypes in my game, so the maps are like so, gameType1Wins, gameType1Losses, gameType2Wins, gameType2Losses etc which i store in a config file, on loading up the game the config populates each map the players config data